# Unsure what "set" is doing in a line of Java code

Tags: java

What does `set` mean in this line of code?

```
List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = set = new ArrayList<>();
```

I've tried to find out what this means but have had no luck so far.

Comment: Do you have set defined anywhere?

Comment: In Java you can make multiple assignments at the same time, e.g. `a = b = c = 5;`  I'm assuming that `set` is a `List<SimpleGrantedAuthority>` that is defined elsewhere.

Comment: Is there an ArrayList `set` declared earlier in the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is essentially chained assignment. `a = b` takes on the value of `b`, and `=` is right associative, so the code is equivalent to:

```java
List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = (set = new ArrayList<>());
```

which is equivalent to:

```java
set = new ArrayList<>();
List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = set;
```

Note that for this to work, `set` has to be previously declared with the correct type.

Comment: Another way to say this is that the assignment operator has a return value, namely the value having been assigned.

Comment: While I totally agree with the answer, I have to say that naming an `ArrayList` as `set` in Java is sadistic.